# IISNode error only on FIRST request after app pool recycle / website restart

Tags: node.js, express, iis-8.5, iisnode

I am running an express.js app, with iisnode as the handler.

Whenever I restart the site in IIS, or recycle the app pool (either manually or by saving the web config after changing a file) the app crashes with a 500.1001 error but only on the very first request. If the same route or any other route is requested thereafter, the app works fine.

I have this code in the index.js entry point

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

which is logging undefined for host, port on the first request, but I have no idea why!

Detailed Error Information:

- Module     iisnode
- Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
- Handler    iisnode
- Error Code     0x00000002
- Requested URL      (app entry point url)
- Physical Path      (physical file path to app entry point)
- Logon Method       Anonymous
- Logon User     Anonymous

Comment: Solved - got rid of namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay from the web config. You can also do this apparently:

https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/07/application-initialization-of-nodejs.html

Comment: If that solved your issue, please post it below as an answer.